# SqlServer better to batch statements or foreach?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Hypothetically, is it better to send N statements to Sql Server (2008), or is it better to send 1 command comprising N statements to Sql Server? In either case, I am running the same statement over a list of objects, and in both cases I would be using named parameters.  Suppose my use case is dumping a cache of log items every few hours.

foreach example

```
var sql = "update blah blah blah where id = @id";
using(var conn = GetConnection())
{
    foreach(var obj in myList)
    {
         var cmd = new SqlCommand() 
         {CommandText = sql, Connection = conn};
         //add params from obj
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

batch example

```
var sql = @"
   update blah blah blah where id = @id1
   update blah blah blah where id = @id2
   update blah blah blah where id = @id3
   -etc";
 using (var conn = GetConnection())
 {
     var cmd = new SqlCommand
     { CommandText = sql, Connection = conn};

     for(int i=0; i<myList.Count; i++)
     {
         //add params: "id" + i  from myList[i]
     }
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

In time tests, the batch version took 15% longer than the foreach version for large inputs. I figure the batch version takes longer to execute because the server has to parse a huge statement and bind up to 2000 parameters.  Supposing Sql Server is on the LAN, is there any advantage to using the batch method?

Comment: I suggest you to you use `for` statement instead of `for-each`, if you can.

Comment: Depending on the update logic's complexity, I might choose to populate a temporary table with an id list and then `update blah blah blah where id in (select id from #temp)`.

Comment: why is a for-loop better if I don't care about the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests would seem to have given you the answer however let me add another. It is preferrable to encapsulate the update into a separate function and call that using a foreach:

```
private function UpdateFoo( int id )
{
    const sql = "Update Foo Where Id = @Id";
    using ( var conn = GetConnection() )
    {
        using ( var cmd = new SqlCommand( sql, conn ) )
        {
            cmd.AddParameterWithValue( "@Id", id )
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

private function UpdateLotsOfFoo()
{
    foreach( var foo in myList )
    {
        UpdateFoo( foo.Id );
    }
}
```

In this setup you are leveraging connection pooling which mitgates the cost of opening and closing connections.

Comment: This uses connection pooling (over the post)? I take that to mean "can leverage prepared statements/caching"?

Comment: @pst - Different issues. First, ADO.NET (and ADO before it) have baked in connection pooling. Thus, in general it is better to open a connection, do some work, and close as soon as possible to return it to the pool. Only later does ADO.NET actually close the connection. Prepared statements are something done by SQL Server or the database engine in general. You get that when you use parameterized queries.

Comment: @thomas in either case, I'm getting 1 connection, opening it, running my command(s), and disposing it. I don't understand how it is better to ask the pool for a potentially new connection in each loop iteration..

Comment: @dan - Because you are not actually getting a new connection. You are getting an already open connection. The reason this is better is encapsulation. It allows you to reuse UpdateFoo. Another reason is that you may later migrate to using multi-threading like Parallel.ForEach and having UpdateFoo encapsulated will make that easier.

Comment: ok, so in this case the update is getting run in a background thread and it's just dumping a bunch of log data.  My main concern is whether I'm stressing the database more by sending 2k commands of 1 statement each, or 1 command containing 2k statements. what do you think?

Comment: @dan - My bet is sending 2K commands is faster than one script with 2k statements. The reason is that databases are designed for lots of volume. Sending one fat statement requires the db to parse it, then build an execution plan and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas - this design can increase overhead of opening / closing connections in a loop.  This is not a preferred practice and should be avoided.  The code below allows the iteration of the statements while using one connection and will be easier on resources (both client and server side).

```
    private void UpdateFoo(int id)
    {
        const string sql  = "Update Foo Where Id = @Id";
        using (var conn = GetConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (var foo in myList)
            {
                UpdateFoo(foo.Id);
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.AddParameterWithValue("@Id", id);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
    }
```